# Visualization tools that can be integrated with Fiware

Tags: fiware

I want to know which tools can be used to visualize data obtained from Orion Context Broker of FIWARE and HDFS.Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

within the FIWARE context, both Knowage and Wirecloud can be used.
You can discover more about Knowage and Wirecloud starting from the FIWARE GE catalogue:

https://catalogue-server.fiware.org/enablers/

They are very different from each other: Knowage is a complete BI solution, while Wirecloud is an application mashup platform. The choice of the right tool depends on the type of visualizations/analyses you want to achieve.

I suggest you to have a look at documentation and examples for both.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion